# Onclick animate and jump to section

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I have this jquery:

```
$('.tbl-link').click(function(){
    $('.tbl-content').animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        //height: '+=300px',
        marginTop: '330px'
    }, 1200).css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
});

$( '#info div:not(:first)' ).hide();

$('#info-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $('#info div').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
}).eq(0).addClass('current');
```

it all works however i want to go a step further i have multiple links on a page and onclick the menu comes down and there is a section which has tabs, in that section i have 3 tabs one for each link, what i want is for if the user clicks on link 2 the menu comes down and shows section 2 for link 2, the same for link 3 but to show section 3 etc.

here is the link to the site: http://www.butterflybuns.com/area51/prices-ordering

what do i need to adjust or add to make it so?

thanks

Comment: Can you format that code?  A little indenting goes a long way.

Comment: done, sorry about that, had problems with putting code on here before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is simply to call `click` on the appropriate tab.  For instance, if you click on the link related to tab 2:

```
$('#info-nav li').eq(1).click();
```